# How to write Some Data in CSV file in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying print some shipment details as a CSV file and I am almost done in implementing this but it does not gives the the option for downloading.It automatically create the file and save it in the  directory mentioned.

I think I am missing _prepareDownloadResponse() function but how do I implement this.

I am using this code ->

```
$file_path = 'sample_shipment.csv';
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $content);
```

Edit:
All this code is in my indexcontroller.php 
full code in indexcontroller.php ->

```
class Company_Manifestupload_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{        
public function indexAction() {
    echo 'Manifestupload Index!';
}
public function bluedartmanifestuploadAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $shipmentIds = $request->getPost('shipment_ids', array());
    $file_path = 'manifest_upload_'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('d-m-Y_H-i-s').'_csv.csv';
    $mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
    $shipment_csv=array();

            /*  Putting data in $shipment_csv[] */
            $mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $shipment_csv);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the csv file downloadable, just put the following code inside the related controller action:

```
$fileName       = 'filename.csv';
$content        = $csvData; //prepare the csv data and return as string
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content); //this will make the csv file downloadable with the $content as contents in it.
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Please find the updated controller action code.

```
public function bluedartmanifestuploadAction() {
    $request        = $this->getRequest();
    $shipmentIds    = $request->getPost('shipment_ids', array());
    $fileName       = 'manifest_upload_'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('d-m-Y_H-i-s').'_csv.csv';

    //prepare csv contents
    #prepare header
    $csv = '';
    $_columns = array(
        "field1",
        "field2",
        //...
    );
    $data = array();
    foreach ($_columns as $column) {
        $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
    }
    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
    #prepare data
    foreach($dataFromShipmentIds as $_data){ //just dummy loop
        $data = array();
        $data[] = $_data['field1'];
        $data[] = $_data['field2'];
        //...
        $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
    }
    //now $csv varaible has csv data as string

    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $csv); 
}
```

**Edit 2**: The above code will only work properly in ideal case.It will not generate proper Csv when there "\n"s and ","s in the fields .To make it work properly one can use code from varien file CSV .I'll add it here-

First  make array of values in $data[] as above  then instead of using `$csv.=implode(',',$data)."\n"` use the below code.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
         if (strpos($value, $delimiter) != false ||
             strpos($value, $enclosure) != false ||
             strpos($value, "\n") != false ||
             strpos($value, "\r") != false ||
             strpos($value, "\t") != false ||
             strpos($value, ' ') != false) {
             $str2 = $enclosure;
             $escaped = 0;
             $len = strlen($value);
             for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
                 if ($value[$i] == $escape_char) {
                     $escaped = 1;
                } else if (!$escaped && $value[$i] == $enclosure) {
                     $str2 .= $enclosure;
                 } else {
                     $escaped = 0;
                 }
                     $str2 .= $value[$i];
             }
             $str2 .= $enclosure;
             $str .= $str2.$delimiter;
         } else {
             $str .= $enclosure.$value.$enclosure.$delimiter;
         }
     }
            $str = substr($str,0,-1);
            $str .= "\n";
```

Comment: It's not working .All this code is in my indexController.php.

Comment: Actually I have made a module which gives a option for printing in _Actions_ Dropdown menu

Comment: Your controller is extending from which class? also paste the code that you have used in your controller action.

Comment: my controller is extending from Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action class.

Comment: Is it possible to do this  with Varien_File_Csv(); class ,as it is provided by magento for printing CSV files and also get the download response.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it is also a possible solution but it would be better if we can do it magento way .

Comment: @ankit thanks. I will try to figure out the magento way and will update the post whenever i got the free time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create downloadable csv of you ordered item's you can use following script.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();
// prepare CSV header
$csv = '';
$_columns = array(
     "Order Id",
     "Product Name",
     "Sku",
     "Price"
);
$data = array();
// prepare CSV header...
foreach ($_columns as $column) {
       $data[] = '"'.$column.'"';
}
$csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
foreach ($orders as $order) {
         $items = $order->getAllItems();
         foreach ($items as $item) {
               $loadProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
               //prepare csv contents
                $data = array();
                $data[] = $order->getId();
                $data[] = $loadProduct['name'];
                $data[] = $loadProduct['sku'];
                $data[] = $loadProduct['price'];

                $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
               //now $csv varaible has csv data as string
    }
}

$this->_redirect('*/*/');
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file.csv', $csv, 'text/csv');
```

For more info visit [here](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-create-csv-files-in-magento.html)